# How to show list of records with order which displays nearby latitude and longitude data first in list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am trying to order records of list to show nearby some latitude and longitude first and then display another remaining data in list, but can't achieve this because I have not much knowledge of order by query. If anyone can help it will be grateful to me. Thanks in advance.

I have one customer class on which I am trying to add order query like this:
customer = Customer.all
customer.where(state: "New york").order('within_radius(41.73061, 72.935242, 20000)' is first)

I want to show all records of newyork state but want to display near by results first in list. How can I do this. Can anyone guide me

Comment: Can you let us know what database you're using? Essentially you will need to get some way of measuring the distance, and either sorting in the database using this method, or in ruby ... It all depends on where you can quantify the distance

Comment: I am using postgresql, I am using geocoder in my app and uses wihin_radius to map distance, but don't know how to sort fetched list @Jad

Comment: I am also storing latitude and longitude in customer table when it created, I only want to order list of customers conditionally like  whithin radius records should display first and all other should display later.

Comment: can you edit your answer to include the code you use to work out the distance, so that we can see what you're currently doing?  if you use three back ticks it should format the test in a code block